# use-package deferred loading for extensions not in :mode

Tags: major-mode, use-package

When moving to `use-package`, I'd to replace

```lisp
(require 'markdown-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.md\\'" . markdown-mode))
```

with

```lisp
(use-package markdown-mode
  :mode "\\.md\\'"
  :config ...
)
```

`use-package`'s documentation on `:defer` says it's unneeded when using `:mode`:

> Defer loading of a package -- this is implied when using ‘:commands’, ‘:bind’, ‘:bind*’, ‘:mode’, ‘:magic’, ‘:hook’, ‘:magic-fallback’, or ‘:interpreter’.  This can be an integer, to force loading after N seconds of idle time, if the package has not already been loaded.

so only when I open a file ending `.md`, will `markdown-mode` be loaded and configured.

However, there're extensions where there're

1. No additions to `auto-mode-alist` e.g. `.rs` files automatically have `rust-mode` as major
2. Some additions to `auto-mode-alist`

```lisp
(use-package cc-mode
  ;; not adding .c, .cpp, .cc, .h, etc. since it's automatically
  ;; associated to the right cc mode
  :mode (("\\.inl\\'" . c++-mode)
         ("\\.mm\\'" . objc-mode))
)
```

In these cases will `use-package` do deferred loading?

When I open a `.c` file, I see that the major mode is rightly `c-mode` but I don't know if this was early/lazy loaded.

Comment: `:commands (cc-mode c-mode)` would defer loading for sure.    You could also check values of mode specific variables, before loading a c-file to verify `cc-mode` hasn't (yet) been loaded.

Comment: Though this doesn't answer the question, this helped me -- thank you. Also for future viewers, it should be `:commands (c++-mode c-mode)`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `c++-mode`, I didn't spot that error!